# Yoast seo and qtranslate x

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, sitemap

I'm using Yoast SEO plugin for sitemap generation for WordPress website with Qtanslate X. I have installed a plugin integration of Yoast SEO with Qtranslate. the sitemap is created as separate xml file for each language. Please let me know it will cause the duplicate content issue in Search engine.
(Or)
Instead of separate xml file for each language, We should create a link with rel="alternate" and hreflang="fr" for all other languages in the same sitemap.xml .

```
<loc> http://www.example.com/aboutus/ </loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/aboutus/>  
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.example.com/fr/aboutus/">
```

Please let me know which is correct?

Thanks,